# How can I split a string into an array on every newline?

Tags: powershell

In my situation, I will have a string that looks like this.

```
$emailList = "example@mail.com
              example2@mail.com
              example3@mail.com"
```

How can I port this into an array with no white-space so it would look like

```
$emailList = @("example@mail.com","example2@mail.com","example3@mail.com"
```

Comment: Look into the `-split` operator and the `trim()` method.

Comment: `-split $emailList` (if the strings themselves don't contain any whitespace) or `$emailList -split '\r?\n'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the comments, if you do this:

```
($emailList -split '\r?\n').Trim()
```

It uses `-split` to separate the list in to an array based on the new line/return charaters and then `.Trim()` to remove any whitespace either side of each string.

Following this the result is now already an array. However if you explicitly want the output to be as a list of comma separated strings surrounded by double quotes you could then do this:

```
(($emailList -split '\r?\n').Trim() | ForEach-Object { '"'+$_+'"' }) -Join ','
```

Which uses `ForEach-Object` to add quote marks around each entry and then uses `-Join` to connect them with a `,`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$emailList = "example@mail.com
              example2@mail.com
              example3@mail.com"
$emailList.Split([Environment]::NewLine,[Stringsplitoptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries).trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

-split on the left side splits on variable whitespace:

```
$emailList = -split 'example@mail.com
              example2@mail.com
              example3@mail.com'
$emailList

example@mail.com
example2@mail.com
example3@mail.com
```

You can also form an array list this.  @() is almost never needed.

```
$emailList = 'example@mail.com','example2@mail.com','example3@mail.com'
```

Or as a shortcut (echo is an alias for write-output):

```
$emailList = echo example@mail.com example2@mail.com example3@mail.com
```